# Eclipse Showing error while starting

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I normally starts my eclipse kepler from command line in ubuntu and its working fine for me from a long period of time. Today its shows the following error and is not getting started. Any help will be appreciated.

---

```
 ** (eclipse:11160): WARNING **: Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=51cd57f60dc1ddcceff7115600000007 --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access the computer from terminal like TTY1 (control+alt+F1) and type this (sudo if needed):

```
sudo rm .Xauthority
```

Then, restart the system.

Take a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145592/x11-initialization-failed).